# VS Code Jupyter Notebook - Cannot select output text

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

How can I select the text in the output area of my VS Code Jupyter Notebook (Python 3.9.7.) (Windows 10)?

I'm not sure what i changed, and I know I could select the text in the past.
I could'nt find this question asked or answered anywhere with a quick google, and I'd appreciate the help. This is surprisingly frustrating, if you can't select text from the output.

[I can select the text in the code editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pObAg.png)

[I cannot select the text in the output area.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjNoP.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well I wouldn't know more information to give. The text in the output used to be able to be selected. But it no longer is for me. I guess this is some bug. As loads of people use VS Code I assumed this was a common issue with known solutions. But I couldn't find anything, so I asked here, hoping to create an answer thread that helped other newbies like me solve this, when they came across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an output tab open for the notebook, try closing that tab. That fixed the issue for me.

Details:

By 'output tab' I mean the the tab that appears after clicking 'Open the full output data in a text editor' as shown here:[image]